Angle between 3 points defined with coordinate
Let's say points A, B and C are defined with coordinate.
Is there a built-in function (let's say \angle{A,B,C}) which calculates the angle between 3 given points in Latex?
I'm aware of the function \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints, but it's not practical since it takes just 2 points and it doesn't work with points defined using coordinate (unless I don't know how to use it).
In the example below the function \angle{A,B,C} should return 60 degrees.
(the question isn't about drawing the angle, it's about calculating the value of the angle)
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,3);
\coordinate (C) at (\fpeval{3*sqrt(3)},\fpeval{-4*sqrt(3)});

\draw[fill] (A) circle (0.05) node[left] {$A$};
\draw[fill] (B) circle (0.05) node[right] {$B$};
\draw[fill] (C) circle (0.05) node[right] {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


The tkz-euclide package calculates angles.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,3);
\coordinate (C) at (\fpeval{3*sqrt(3)},\fpeval{-4*sqrt(3)});

\draw[fill] (A) circle (0.05) node[left] {$A$};
\draw[fill] (B) circle (0.05) node[right] {$B$};
\draw[fill] (C) circle (0.05) node[right] {$C$};
\tkzFindAngle(A,B,C)
\tkzGetAngle{angleABC}
\edef\angleABC{\fpeval{round(\angleABC)}}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C)
\tkzMarkAngle(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.3](A,B,C){$\angleABC^\circ$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


